# Ставится ли запятая перед "чем"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Вступил не ранее(,) чем по истечении одного месяца".

Answer (score 4):

Нет.

Запятая не ставится внутри сочетаний *(не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем* и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения.